# Turning on and off pin change interrupts ATtiny85

Tags: arduino, avr, attiny

I know that pin change interrupts can be turned on for the ATtiny85 by enabling PCIs using the GIMSK register, then setting which pins to turn it on for by using the PCMSK register, then lastly calling sei() to enable them. The following code achieves this:

```
GIMSK = 0b00100000;
PCMSK = 0b00011111;
sei();
```

I am somewhat unsure as to how I'm supposed to turn them off. Is cli() all that is necessary, or do I need to reset the registers as I did in the following snippet:

```
GIMSK = 0b00000000;
PCMSK = 0b00000000;
cli();
```

Any insight would be appreciated. I am using the Arduino platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all`sei()` and `cli()` enable/disable **all** interrupts, not just the pin change ones. Unless you don't want any interrupts at all, you shouldn't be using `cli()` when trying to disable pin change interrupts.

Clearing the `PCIE` bit in `GIMSK` is sufficient to turn off pin change interrupts. You don't even need to clear the `PCMSK` register.

Obligatory excerpt from [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf) (page 51):

> When the PCIE bit is set (one) and the I-bit in the Status Register (SREG) is set (one), pin change interrupt is enabled. Any change on any enabled PCINT[5:0] pin will cause an interrupt. The corresponding interrupt of Pin
>   Change Interrupt Request is executed from the PCI Interrupt Vector. PCINT[5:0] pins are enabled individually by the PCMSK0 Register.

Pin change interrupts are only enabled when the `PCIE` bit in `GIMSK` is set (one). Otherwise they are disabled.

The global interrupt flag in the `SREG` must also be set for interrupts to occur (`sei()`), however if you are already using interrupts in your design this bit is probably already set.